# Changing Page URL To PHP

Tags: php, url

Hi I want to convert pages URL like `www.example.com/pictures.php?title=yyoy` to something like `www.example.com/page/yoyo.php`

How can I do this?

`www.example.com/pictures.php?title=yyoy` these pages are generated when someone upload image to my website so I want to turn these types of URL to like above shown example.

Because these pages can't be index in search engines. Thanks

**Picture.php**

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['title'])){

$page_id = $_GET['title'];

    $select_query = "select * from save_data where Title='$page_id'";

$run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){

    $post_id = $row['ID']; 
    $post_title = $row['Title'];
    $post_image = $row['Name'];

$page_title = $_GET['title'];
header('uploads/ ' . $page_title . '.php')

?>
<center>
<h2>
<a href="pictures.php?title=<?php echo $post_title; ?>">

<?php echo $post_title; ?>

</a></center>

</h2>

<center><img src="uploads/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"  /></center>


<?php } }?>
```

Comment: Take a look at how the .htaccess file works, it can help

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but you should use rules similar to the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^pictures.php?title=(.+)$  page/$1.php  [R]
```

Note that, you will need `mod_rewrite` enabled for this to work in `apache2`

Comment: have written this code in .htaccess file but nothing happened  @Stoic

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would create an in-between page when posting from a form, but in your case your link looks like this:

```
www.example.com/pictures.php?title=yoyo
```

So it directs you to pictures.php with a variable 'title' in the URL.

So on your pictures.php page use:

```
$page_title = $_GET['title'];
```

And when you want to go to yoyo.php:

```
header('Location: $page_title.php')
```

From your edit this code will redirect the page but it will not display the last HTML:

```
<?php 
  include("connection.php");

  if(isset($_GET['title'])){

    $page_id = $_GET['title'];

    $select_query = "select * from save_data where Title='$page_id'";

    $run_query = mysqli_query($select_query);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)){

      $post_id = $row['ID'];       //Just make sure the values between [''] match -
      $post_title = $row['Title']; //your columns in database.
      $post_image = $row['Name'];
    }

    header('Location:uploads/$post_title.php');
?>
```

This will be left out:

```
<center>
  <h2>
  <a href="pictures.php?title=<?php echo $post_title; ?>">

  <?php echo $post_title; ?>

  </a></center>

  </h2>

  <center><img src="uploads/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"  /></center>


  <?php } }?>
```

Comment: Don't understand this @J2D8T

Comment: My `picture.php page` is not looking like this but still it's not working check MY Post I have updated it @J2D8T

Comment: Still not now its giving this in url `/$page_title.php`

Comment: Now it's saying 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\pictures.php on line 21`

Comment: Sorry `header('Location:uploads/$page_title.php');`

Comment: `/uploads/$page_title.php` Object not found

Comment: `header('Location:uploads/$post_title.php');` variable is wrong

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer here: [Masking $_GET variables of the URL when passing pages in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007695/masking-get-variables-of-the-url-when-passing-pages-in-php?rq=1)
That will tell you how to mask your URLs.

Alternatively, you could have these files uploaded to a directory in your file structure called "page/" Then you can access the files (as a download) inside the page directory with www.example.com/page/filename.php

Answer (score 1):

URE This one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^pictures.php?title=(.+)$  page/$1.php  [R, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .htaccess file. Add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^picture/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php$ pictures.php?title=$1
</IfModule>
```

If you're using a local server like WAMP, be sure to turn on de `mod_rewrite` or `rewrite_module` of apache and reboot the server.

You should also Google for Regular Expressions.
Let me know if it was useful.

Comment: I just put that code in .htaccess file but nothing happened no errors nothing changed

Comment: @user3023297 Can u post a screenshot when your enter //yoursite.com/picture/my-pic.php (remember to replace "my-pic" for an existing image.